# Converting Smooks CSV file to JAVA ,I got No ClassLoaders found for: au.com.bytecode.opencsv.CSVReader

Tags: java, https, io, richfaces, smooks

Now Im usimg smooks for converting csv file to java so Iam got Exception 
No ClassLoaders found for: au.com.bytecode.opencsv.CSVReader ,

Im getting Exception is

```
  15:03:41,263 ERROR [STDERR] org.milyn.SmooksException: Smooks Filtering operation failed.
15:03:41,264 ERROR [STDERR]     at org.milyn.Smooks._filter(Smooks.java:538)
15:03:41,264 ERROR [STDERR]     at org.milyn.Smooks.filterSource(Smooks.java:475)
15:03:41,264 ERROR [STDERR]     at com.manam.mobee.migrationCustomerManagement.MigrationCustomerHome.runSmooksTransform(MigrationCustomerHome.java:76)
15:03:41,264 ERROR [STDERR]     at com.manam.mobee.migrationCustomerManagement.MigrationCustomerHome.displyTempCustomers(MigrationCustomerHome.java:115)
15:03:41,264 ERROR [STDERR]     at com.manam.mobee.migrationCustomerManagement.MigrationCustomerHome.listener(MigrationCustomerHome.java:144)
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: au/com/bytecode/opencsv/CSVReader
15:03:41,268 ERROR [STDERR]     at org.milyn.csv.CSVReader.parse(CSVReader.java:314)
15:03:41,268 ERROR [STDERR]     at org.milyn.delivery.sax.SAXParser.parse(SAXParser.java:70)
15:03:41,268 ERROR [STDERR]     at org.milyn.delivery.sax.SmooksSAXFilter.doFilter(SmooksSAXFilter.java:75)
15:03:41,268 ERROR [STDERR]     at org.milyn.delivery.sax.SmooksSAXFilter.doFilter(SmooksSAXFilter.java:61)
15:03:41,268 ERROR [STDERR]     at org.milyn.Smooks._filter(Smooks.java:516)
15:03:41,269 ERROR [STDERR]     ... 92 more
15:03:41,269 ERROR [STDERR] Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: No ClassLoaders found for: au.com.bytecode.opencsv.CSVReader
15:03:41,269 ERROR [STDERR]     at org.jboss.mx.loading.LoadMgr3.beginLoadTask(LoadMgr3.java:306)
15:03:41,269 ERROR [STDERR]     at org.jboss.mx.loading.RepositoryClassLoader.loadClassImpl(RepositoryClassLoader.java:521)
15:03:41,269 ERROR [STDERR]     at org.jboss.mx.loading.RepositoryClassLoader.loadClass(RepositoryClassLoader.java:415)
15:03:41,269 ERROR [STDERR]     at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
15:03:41,269 ERROR [STDERR]     ... 97 more
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Probably you are missing the opencsv-XX.jar from your classpath (XX represents the opencsv version, like: 1.6 or 1.7). Or it's not in the right place for your container to see it (check WEB-INF/lib).